# Checking status of remote services

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

this method is used to obtain the status of services on a remote server:

```
private getServiceStatus(tMsg, exceptionCollection, input)
    {
        nsDataTypes.GetServiceStatusOutput output = new nsDataTypes.GetServiceStatusOutput();

        try
        {
            nsSEMLib.ServiceControllerEx[] svcs = new nsSEMLib.ServiceControllerEx[] { new nsSEMLib.ServiceControllerEx(input.ServiceName, input.ServerName) };
            nsSEMLib.ServiceControllerEx svc = svcs[0];
            System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus s = svc.Status;

            switch (s)
            {
                case System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Running:
                    output.ServiceStatus = nsDataTypes.ServiceStatus.Started;
                    break;
                case System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped:
                    output.ServiceStatus = nsDataTypes.ServiceStatus.Stopped;
                    break;
                case System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Paused:
                    output.ServiceStatus = nsDataTypes.ServiceStatus.Paused;
                    break;
                default:
                    output.ServiceStatus = nsDataTypes.ServiceStatus.NotExists;
                    break;
            }

            try
            {
                nsSEMLib.ServiceControllerEx.ServiceStartMode startMode = svc.StartupType;

                switch (startMode)
                {
                    case nsSEMLib.ServiceControllerEx.ServiceStartMode.Automatic:
                        output.ServiceStartMode = nsDataTypes.ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
                        break;
                    case nsSEMLib.ServiceControllerEx.ServiceStartMode.Manual:
                        output.ServiceStartMode = nsDataTypes.ServiceStartMode.Manual;
                        break;
                    case nsSEMLib.ServiceControllerEx.ServiceStartMode.Disabled:
                        output.ServiceStartMode = nsDataTypes.ServiceStartMode.Disabled;
                        break;
                    case nsSEMLib.ServiceControllerEx.ServiceStartMode.Default:
                        output.ServiceStartMode = nsDataTypes.ServiceStartMode.Default;
                        break;
                    default:
                        output.ServiceStartMode = nsDataTypes.ServiceStartMode.Default;
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            output.ServiceStatus = nsDataTypes.ServiceStatus.NotExists;
            ex = null;
        }
        return output;
    }
```

During debugging when the code gets to this point:

```
System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus s = svc.Status;
```

I am getting this error:

> ex = {"Service NGArchivalEP_002 was not found on computer
>   'servername'."}

However if I check this server I can see the service exists but it is in a stopped status. So instead of generating an error my app should have read the service was stopped and depicted this on the webpage. I think this is related to a recent ID change that we released but how do i find out which ID my web app is using to connect to these remote servers? Is it the Id defined in the App Pool?

Comment: check what is inside svcs[0]?

Comment: and the `status` property value there?

Comment: that's where the error is generated when the code attempts to check the status

Comment: status = 0
also the Description property is showing this error message:
base {System.SystemException} = {"Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"}

Comment: have managed to resolve this - the App Pool ID need to be added to the admin group on the remote server